# How to alias complex type constructor in typescript?

Tags: oop, typescript

I am using a custom library, and for some types I have to write:

```
 import * as pipeline from 'custom-pipeline';
 import {MapTransform} from 'custom-pipeline';

 export const createTransform = (appConfig: IAppConfig):
   MapTransform<ISomeData, IFoo> |
   MapTransform<ISomeData, IBar> => {

   switch(appConfig.createType) {
       case 'foo':
           return new pipeline.MapTransform<ISomeData, IFoo>((data: ISomeData) => {...});
       case 'bar':
           return new pipeline.MapTransform<ISomeData, IBar>((data: ISomeData) => {...});
   }
 }
```

Especially the verbose constructor is irking me. I can I alias the types alright:

```
 type FooTransform = MapTransform<ISomeData, IFoo>;
 type BarTransform = MapTransform<ISomeData, IBar>;
```

Yet I cannot do:

```
 new FooTransform((data: ISomeData) => {...});
 new BarTransform((data: ISomeData) => {...});
```

throwing an error like:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FooTransform'.
```

I assume it's because I only have a type and not a class? Yet how can I alias the constructor in a way that I can do `new FooTransform` as above?

The definition of `MapTransform` looks like:

```
export declare class MapTransform<A, B> extends BaseTransform<A, B> {
    constructor(private mapFunc: (val: A) => B);
}
```

I can reduce the constructor to this:

```
fooMapFunction = (data: ISomeData): IFoo => {...};
new MapTransform<ISomeData, IFoo>(mapFunction);
```

Albeit it's not en par with a `new FooTransform(fooMapFunction)`.

Comment: I guess it's currently not supported? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2552

Answer (score 9):

Your assumption is correct, type declarations are **compile-time** only, thus you can't perform any operations on them (including instantiation with `new`).

### Solution 1: Type Assertion

Let's assume the superclass looks like this:

```
class MapTransform<T1> { 
    constructor(public readonly data: T1) { /* ... */ }
}
```

To create a specialised type alias, you can do this:

```
type TransformA = MapTransform<number>;
```

From the perspective of the superclass `MapTransform`, there's no difference between `MapTransform<A>`, `MapTransform<B>` and so on (that's the point of generics), so we can safely assign the constructor function of class `MapTransform` to a constant `TransformA`. Calling `new TransformA()` is, **at runtime**, identical to calling `new MapTransform<number>()`:

```
const TransformA = <{ new (data: number): TransformA; }>MapTransform;
```

Notice the type assertion? This tells the TypeScript compiler to treat the assigned value `MapTransform` as an object which constructs an object of type `TransformA` when instantiating it with `new`. We can now write:

```
const a = new TransformA(123);
a.data.toExponential(); // works
```

BTW, what the TypeScript compiler actually sees is this ...

```
const TransformA = <{ new (data: number): MapTransform<number>; }>MapTransform;
```

... because type `TransformA ≡ MapTransform<number>`.

Be aware that all of these will evaluate `true`:

- `new TransformA(123) instanceof TransformA`
- `new TransformA(123) instanceof MapTransform`
- `new MapTransform<number>(123) instanceof TransformA`
- `new MapTransform<number>(123) instanceof MapTransform`

Here's the example in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20MapTransform%3CT%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20readonly%20data%3A%20T)%20%7B%20%2F*%20...%20*%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TransformA%20%3D%20MapTransform%3Cnumber%3E%3B%0D%0Aconst%20TransformA%20%3D%20%3C%7B%20new%20(data%3A%20number)%3A%20TransformA%3B%20%7D%3EMapTransform%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20new%20TransformA(123)%3B%0D%0Aa.data.toExponential()%3B%20%2F%2F%20works%0D%0A%0D%0A).

### Solution 2: Subclassing

Again, let's assume the superclass looks like this:

```
class MapTransform<T1> { 
    constructor(public readonly data: T1) { /* ... */ }
}
```

With subclassing, the solution is simple: Extend the superclass and pass the desired type parameters along in the extends clause.

```
class TransformA extends MapTransform<number> { }
```

Et voilà, you now have a constructor that works at runtime as well as a type that works at compile-time.

Unlike the first solution, the following 2 expressions will evaluate `true` ...

- `new TransformA(123) instanceof TransformA`
- `new TransformA(123) instanceof MapTransform`

... while these will evaluate `false`:

- `new MapTransform<number>(123) instanceof TransformA`
- `new MapTransform<number>(123) instanceof MapTransform`

#### Solution 2.1: Anonymous Subclassing

If you only need the constructor alias but not the type alias, this might come in handy:

```
const TransformA = class extends MapTransform<number> { };
```

This is called a *class expression* and can be used like every other expression, for example:

```
class App {
    private static TransformA = class extends MapTransform<number> { };

    public doStuff() {
        return new App.TransformA(123);
    }
}
```

### More on Types

If you're interested, here's a few more links on the topic:

- [Named Types in TypeScript Spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#37-named-types)
- [Type Assertions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html)
- [TypeScript Handbook: Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), specifically section "Difference between the static and instance sides of classes"
- [Class Expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/497)

---

### EDIT

You wrote you've had issues applying these solutions to a class that expects a function as a parameter, so here's another [example in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20BaseTransform%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20MapTransform%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20extends%20BaseTransform%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20mapFunc%3A%20(val%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20B)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20---%20Solution%201%20---%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TransformA_1%20%3D%20MapTransform%3Cstring%2C%20number%3E%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20ITransformA_1Constructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new(mapFunc%3A%20(val%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20number)%3A%20MapTransform%3Cnumber%2C%20number%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20TransformA_1%20%3D%20%3CITransformA_1Constructor%3EMapTransform%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20instantiation%3A%0D%0Anew%20TransformA_1(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20accept%20generic%20type%20%60A%60%20as%20a%20parameter%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(val%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20return%20generic%20type%20%60B%60%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20---%20Solution%202%20---%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TransformA_2%20extends%20MapTransform%3Cstring%2C%20number%3E%20%7B%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20instantiation%3A%0D%0Anew%20TransformA_2(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20accept%20generic%20type%20%60A%60%20as%20a%20parameter%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(val%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20return%20generic%20type%20%60B%60%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20---%20Solution%202.1%20---%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20TransformA_3%20%3D%20class%20extends%20MapTransform%3Cstring%2C%20number%3E%20%7B%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20instantiation%3A%0D%0Anew%20TransformA_3(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20accept%20generic%20type%20%60A%60%20as%20a%20parameter%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(val%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20return%20generic%20type%20%60B%60%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A).

Comment: I have updated my question with the constructor of my MapTransform constructor. I still have troubles applying your solution to such a constructor demanding a function.

Comment: @k0pernikus I've added another example, hope it helps.

Comment: Such an awesome answer. I'm without words to describe it. <3 Thank you.

Comment: The playground for the first solution doesn't seem to work anymore. Also I'm getting a eslint warning `TransformA is already defined`. Is this expected?